# Calling delegates later aka. delegate queue

Tags: c#, delegates, dynamic-invoke, multicastdelegate

so I'm pretty new to c# and I've came around this problem:
I have some methods that invoke different delegates (with potentially different argument types). However these delegates shouldn't be called right away. If the main Thread is running a delegate, they should run afterwards, kinda like queuing the delegate and running it later.
Now I could probably use DynamicInvoke but I don't know if it will slow the queue down too much, besides I know what the delegate type is and what kind of parameter it should look for, so its not really runtime dependent. 
Please help me if you can, I really need an answer.

Thanks everybody (who responds)

Comment: I think you can do this with the Reactive Extensions library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is doing that could be use of `Tasks` (beginning from `.NET 4.0`)

Can have a look on

[Asynchronous methods, C# iterators, and Tasks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/30/9809774.aspx)

how to create scheduling tasks, like, seems, in your case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I can only use .net 3.5

Comment: at this point may be more appropriate could be actually an option offered in comment, so [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609)

Comment: @user1316459: there is actually another solution yet, may be more apporiate for *scheduling*, it's a [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). Have a look on it, could be more useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work if, instead of adding your delegates directly, you *wrapped* them into new `Action` delegates which simply invoke them, passing all their parameters? For example:

```
List<Action> pending = new List<Action>();
pending.Add(() => MethodThatTakesNoParameters());
pending.Add(() => MethodThatTakesOneParameter(param));
pending.Add(() => MethodThatTakesThreeParameters(param1, param2, param3));
```